# Deleting Custom Label Placements in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

I was doing some trial and error by creating Custom Label styles and placements and have achieved what I set out for. Problem is, I've got a few 'bad' custom label placements I want to delete and only keep the good ones.

I know how to delete Styles where do I delete the custom label placement icons?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but it came up on the first page in a Google search, and I did not find a direct answer elsewhere, so I will answer with my hard-won solution:  In the catalog pane, expand "styles", then double-click "favorites".  A catalog tab will open in the map view pane.  At bottom, right, there should be a "Style Classes" drop-down.  Expand that, then double-click "maplex label placement".  Your list of favorites should appear at left.  Right click on whatever one you want to delete and send it packing!  Where I finally found this was by reading the entire "manage styles" page in Pro documentation.  It doesn't tell you how to delete a style, but it was enough to get me on the correct track.  As a disclaimer, I didn't even know what a style was until I had this problem, so it took awhile to even know which wiki to read.